# Fill in blank dates for a grouped query which returns some null rows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am over my head trying to get data for statistics over the course of n number of days. I don't really care about the output format, as long as it shows the dates in order, and the values as an array... The all_data query (below) will get all the values for determined time period, but it won't create rows for dates where there are no values. The goal is to be able to output this:

```
# Get 10 (for example) days of data->

[
    {date:'datetime-day-ago-10', values: [{foo:'bar', foo2:'bar2', foo3:'bar'3}]}
    {date:'datetime-day-ago-9', values: [{foo:'bar', foo2:'bar2', foo3:'bar'3}]}
    {date:'datetime-day-ago-8', values: []}
    {date:'datetime-day-ago-7', values: [{foo:'bar', foo2:'bar2', foo3:'bar'3}]}
    {date:'datetime-day-ago-6', values: []}
    {date:'datetime-day-ago-5', values: []}
    {date:'datetime-day-ago-4', values: [{foo:'bar', foo2:'bar2', foo3:'bar'3}]}
    {date:'datetime-day-ago-3', values: [{foo:'bar', foo2:'bar2', foo3:'bar'3}]}
    {date:'datetime-day-ago-2', values: []}
    {date:'datetime-day-ago-1', values: []}
]
```

Here's the method I am using at this point.

```
def counts

    from = params[:days].to_i.days.ago.to_time.beginning_of_day
    to = 0.days.ago.to_time.end_of_day

    all_data = current_user.values.all
                .where(field_id: params[:field_id], created_at: from .. to)
                .where.not(input: nil)
                .order(input: :desc)
                .group_by { |value| value['created_at'].to_date}
                .map {|k,v| [k,v]}

    grouped = (0..params[:days].to_i-1).to_a.inject([]) do |memo, i|
        if all_data[i].present?
            date = all_data[i][0].to_time
            values = all_data[i][1].group_by { |value| value.input }.map { |k, v| {input:k, count:v.length} }.sort! { |x,y| x['input'] <=> y['input']}
            total = 0
            values.each do |value|
                total = total + value[:count]
            end
        else

            # This is where I can't figure out how to assign a date for rows which have no data.

            date = ((i-params[:days].to_i+1)*-(1)).days.ago.beginning_of_day

        end
        memo << {'date': date, 'total': total || 0, 'values': values || []}
        memo
    end

    grouped = grouped.sort_by { |day| day['date'] }
    render json: grouped
end

# Sample of entire output for 10 days

0: {date: "2015-10-31T00:00:00.000-07:00", total: 15,…} <- 10-31-2015 HAS VALUES
1: {date: "2015-11-01T00:00:00.000-07:00", total: 49,…} <- 11-01-2015 HAS VALUES
2: {date: "2015-11-02T00:00:00.000-08:00", total: 10,…} <- 11-02-2015 HAS VALUES
3: {date: "2015-11-03T00:00:00.000-08:00", total: 21,…} <- 11-03-2015 HAS VALUES
4: {date: "2015-10-30T00:00:00.000-07:00", total: 0, values: []}
5: {date: "2015-10-31T00:00:00.000-07:00", total: 0, values: []}  \
6: {date: "2015-11-01T00:00:00.000-07:00", total: 0, values: []}    -  No matter what I try I can't get these dates to be the 5 days before 10-31-2015...
7: {date: "2015-11-02T00:00:00.000-08:00", total: 0, values: []}  /
8: {date: "2015-11-03T00:00:00.000-08:00", total: 0, values: []}
9: {date: "2015-11-04T00:00:00.000-08:00", total: 0, values: []} <- 11-04-2015 This should appear up there ^ under the last HAS VALUES row
```

So, how can I properly create dates for null value rows? And then how can I make sure they fall into the correct order? Like I said I am over my head on this. Algorithms are not my cup of tea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get a little specific in parts, but here's how I managed to get the desired output. I decided to have this rails controller give me the exact input I'll need for my Angular Google Charts, but I made it clear where the question is directly answered In terms of a method to fill in missing dates and missing row values:

```
        from = params[:from] || (params[:days].to_i-1).days.ago.to_date
        to = params[:to] || 0.days.ago.to_date

        all_data = current_user.values.all
                    .where(field_id: params[:field_id], created_at: from.beginning_of_day .. to.end_of_day)
                    .where.not(input: nil)
                    .order(input: :desc)
                    .group_by { |value| [value['created_at'].to_date, value['input']] }
                    .map { |k, v| {'date': k.first, 'input': k.last, 'count': v.length} }

        # the object which will hold the data to be returned

        grouped = {:cols => [], :rows => [] }

        # Populate columns with a determined set of values for inputs
        diffvals = Array.new
        all_data.each { |day| diffvals.push day[:input] }
        diffvals = diffvals.uniq
        diffvals.each { |input| grouped[:cols].push({'id': "#{input}-id", 'label': input, 'type': 'number'}) }
        grouped[:cols].unshift({'id': 'day', 'label': 'Date', 'type': 'string'})

        ##
        ##  This and the next commented section answer the question:
        ## 
        # Create a set of dates that the actual data will be merged into
        zeros = Array.new
        (0..params[:days].to_i-1).each do |n|
            diffvals.each do |input|
                hash = Hash.new
                hash[:date], hash[:input], hash[:count] = n.days.ago.to_date, input, 0
                zeros.push hash
            end
        end

        ##
        ##
        ##
        # Group the data by date after mapping the actual data onto the premade set of dates
        data_by_date = zeros.map do |first_hash| 
            all_data.each do |second_hash|
                if first_hash[:date] == second_hash[:date] && first_hash[:input] == second_hash[:input]
                    first_hash[:count] = second_hash[:count]
                    break
                end
            end
            first_hash
        end.group_by { |i| i[:date]}

        # Populate rows of data
        data_by_date.each_with_index do |(date, values), day|
            #
            # The first column is the date
            grouped[:rows][day] = {c: [{ v: date }] }

            #
            # Then columns of value inputs
            (0..grouped[:cols].length-2).each { |value| grouped[:rows][day][:c].push({v: values[value][:count] }) }

            #
            # Then a column for the total of all value counts
            grouped[:rows][day][:c].push({v: values.map {|v| v[:count]}.reduce(0, :+) })

        end 

        grouped[:cols].push({'id': "s", 'label': "Total", 'type': 'number'})

        render json: grouped
```

Here's a sample set of data. Favorite color, 3 possible color choices. Over 5 days:

```
cols:
    0: {id: "day", label: "Date", type: "string"}
    1: {id: "Red-id", label: "Red", type: "number"}
    2: {id: "Green-id", label: "Green", type: "number"}
    3: {id: "Blue-id", label: "Blue", type: "number"}
    4: {id: "s", label: "Total", type: "number"}
rows:
    0: {c: [{v: "2015-11-01"}, {v: 18}, {v: 23}, {v: 8}, {v: 49}]}
    1: {c: [{v: "2015-11-02"}, {v: 4}, {v: 4}, {v: 2}, {v: 10}]}
    2: {c: [{v: "2015-11-03"}, {v: 5}, {v: 16}, {v: 0}, {v: 21}]}
    3: {c: [{v: "2015-11-04"}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}
    4: {c: [{v: "2015-11-05"}, {v: 0}, {v: 1}, {v: 6}, {v: 7}]}
```

This is exactly what is needed for the Angular Google Chart plugin

Answer (score 0):

May be, you can come from this side:

```
grouped = (from.to_date..to.to_date).each do |dt|
  existing_data = all_data.detect{ |data| data.first == dt }
  if existing_data
    # you code for existing date
  else
    # you code for non-existing date
  end
  # ...
end

# And, I think, it is not required in this case
#grouped = grouped.sort_by { |day| day['date'] }
```